# Teamcity agent timeout connecting to CVS

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cvs

Does anyone know a reason why a Teamcity build agent would timeout when connecting to a successfully tested CVS repository?

So, I have a CVS repository (don't ask!) which I'm trying to hook up to a TeamCity build.  I've added the VCS root, and pressed the "Test Connection" button and been told "Connection Successful".  Yet, when I come to use the VCS root in the build agent I just get a timeout.

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Problem collecting changes for 'TMC :: Map Client' : Error collecting changes for VCS root 'InVehicle\MapClient'
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

The version of TeamCity is the latest one available (6.0), and it's currently running on the Professional License.

Our lan has a proxy, but when I put the proxy details into TeamCity I can't connect via the dashboard.

The Build Web Server and Build Agent are both on the same machine and they are both running as Local System accounts, so I'm failing to see why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm convinced that this behaviour is the result of a bug in CruiseControl.Net and CVS.  The actual solution?  Abandon CVS, which we have finally done.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling agent checkout and settings VCS Checkout Mode to "Automatically On Server"

You can look at the agent/server logs to get more info about what is going wrong.

Comment: All I'm seeing is the same timeout exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH way of configuring VCS.

add deploy keys to your git repo and add keys into team city

Comment: Six years after asking this question I solved it by moving to companies with decent source control. :)